# A slider into a slider

Tags: html, slider

after a quick search i didn t found what i was looking.
**I want to know if it is possible to do a slider with the main content of my html (only text and div) and other sliders inside.**
The next or previous will be element of my menu. (If I click on the first element of my menu it shows page 1.html, if i click on the second it shows page2.html in the slider.)
I use bootsrap 3 my slider must work on mobil-first. I've already tryed it with bootrap slider but it does not work because using different bootsrap slider in the same page is not a good idea...

Thanks for reading.
Captainlawid.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code of what you've tried yet, so the community can help you.

Comment: Thanks i'm glad to be here ! Sorry I can't provide my code it's confidential and i will not ask you to do my job, I only want to know if it is possible to use a slider in main page with other sliders inside. if you have an example i'll be happy.